# Tensorflow Probability CDF lower than it's PDF value

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, probability, tensorflow-probability

I've been testing Tensorflow Probability on some use cases and have some error. Working backwards, I found that, at least in the Normal distribution, you can see that while the PDF value for 0.9568... is 7.69...e-22, the CDF is 7.621...e-24. That is technically not possible in the theoretical Normal distribution nor on the empirical. Any ideas of what is happening or what did I miss? See the code and the results below:

```
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

tfd = tfp.distributions
tfb = tfp.bijectors

dist = tfd.Normal(loc=1.0, scale=0.1)
print('sample   :', dist.sample(3).numpy()) #Samples 3 numbers
print('prob     :',dist.prob((0,1,2)).numpy()) #Calculates the probabilities for positions 0,1,2
print('log_prob :',dist.log_prob((0,1,2)).numpy()) #Same as above just log
print('cdf      :',dist.cdf((0,1,2)).numpy()) #Calculates the cummulative distributions
print('mean     :',dist.mean().numpy()) #Returns the mean of the distribution
print('stddev   :',dist.stddev().numpy())
```

```
Resuls: 

sample   : [0.95685613 1.0321676  1.1132953 ]
prob     : [7.6946093e-22 3.9894230e+00 7.6946093e-22]
log_prob : [-48.616352    1.3836466 -48.616352 ]
cdf      : [7.619853e-24 5.000000e-01 1.000000e+00]
mean     : 1.0
stddev   : 0.1
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that may found the error event!

The CDF seems lower than the PDF value

Comment: This is a totally normal occurrence.

Comment: How? CDF cannot be mathematically lower than it's PDF value

Comment: It absolutely can in a continuous distribution. Look at [this figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#/media/File:Normal_Distribution_PDF.svg) for normal distributions on Wikipedia. For a variance of 0.2, the PDF is >0.8 at x=0, yet the CDF has to be 0.5 at x=0 since it's the median. And so the PDF is larger than the CDF.

Comment: Ufff, no way! In any distribution, moreover in the Normal, the PDF is the discretion at level 1 unit of a continuous variable (the area of the frequency of such value). Meanwhile, the CDF is the integral (the sum) of all areas until such point. Bascically the AUC (CDF) for your example has more density than such PDF. I don't get your point, sorry. I could be wrong, but I don't get it, maybe another example? Thanks for your patience

Comment: Sorry, I was on holiday. Here is another example. Take a uniform distribution on the interval x in [0, 1]. The pdf is exactly y=1 everywhere. However, the cdf grows from y=0 to y=1 over the interval. For example, the CDF is y=0 at x=0. PDF > CDF.

Comment: Nice example. Thanks for your support @xdurch0!

Comment: You're welcome, but I think it's more important to understand the general principle rather than specific examples. For continuous distributions, the PDF can be arbitrarily large for certain x because you are integrating for the CDF, so as long ast he PDF is only large over a small intervall, it's fine. The CDF can never be larger than 1, on the other hand. However for _discrete_ distributions, you are right that the "PDF" can never be larger than the "CDF" (quotation marks because those terms don't apply to discrete distributions).